# Word "content" appears twice

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I have a document and in the first page I have a \tableofcontents, when I'm adding a header in this page word "content" appears also in header, how to avoid word "content" in the header?

P.S: "Содержание" means "content"

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabu}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
\rhead{
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | X[0.15,l,p] |  X[0.3,l,p] | X[0.3,l,p] | X[0.3,l,p] |     }
\hline
 \textbf{LOGO} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{  {{title}}  }    \\  \hline
               & \textbf{ № УКД:} & \textbf{Версия:}   & \textbf{Страница в документе:} \\ \hline
               &         &         & \thepage  \hspace{1mm}  из \pageref{LastPage} \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace{1cm}

\tableofcontents
\section{\large \textbf{\textsc{Цель}}}

\section{\large \textbf{\textsc{Область применения}}}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: This does not compile for me. Please reduce the code to the minimum and try to keep out anything which is not needed in order to show the error. Is the Russian font or language important here? Is the table needed here?

Comment: You should use package `titlesec` or something similar to style your section titles. Don't do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first occurrence of *Content* comes from your header. You define `rhead{}` but you forgot to define `\lhead{}` as empty.

This MWE do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
\rhead{
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | X[0.15,l,p] |  X[0.3,l,p] | X[0.3,l,p] | X[0.3,l,p] |     }
\hline
 \textbf{LOGO} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{  {{title}}  }    \\  \hline
               & \textbf{ № УКД:} & \textbf{Версия:}   & \textbf{Страница в документе:} \\ \hline
               &         &         & \thepage  \hspace{1mm}  из \pageref{LastPage} \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
}
\lhead{}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace{1cm}

\tableofcontents
\section{\large \textbf{\textsc{Цель}}}

\section{\large \textbf{\textsc{Область применения}}}

\end{document}
```